# Load the resource after downloading(ios)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am downloading the resources from server and writing it to the documents directory successfully by using this code below

```
NSString *fileName = [[[NSURL URLWithString:url] path] lastPathComponent];

NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *folder = [pathArr objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSLog(@"File written");

NSError *writeError = nil;

[webData writeToURL: fileURL options:0 error:&writeError];
if( writeError) {
    NSLog(@" Error in writing file %@' : \n %@ ", filePath , writeError );
    return;
}
NSLog(@"%@",fileURL);
```

Now I want to access those files to use it.I have tried this code

```
-(UIImage *) loadImage:(NSString *)fileName ofType:(NSString *)extension inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath
{

   UIImage * result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", directoryPath, fileName, extension]];
   return result;
}
```

Now method used is like this:

```
UIImage *imageFromWeb = [self loadImage:@"metaioman" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:folder];

_imgview.image=imageFromWeb;
```

But no luck...please help

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly check file exists using NSFileManager.

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *pathForFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.%@", directoryPath, fileName, extension]

UIImage * result = nil;
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:pathForFile]){ 
    //file exists
    result = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathForFile];
}
else
{
   //file doesnot exists or wrong filename.
}
return result;
```

**Reference** : http://beageek.biz/save-and-load-uiimage-in-documents-directory-on-iphone-xcode-ios/

Comment: Yes ,you were right.. file doesn't exist..But I don't know what I am doing wrong..Any suggestions for the above code would be helpful...thanks